# Ionic 1.3 hides NavBar when caching is disabled

Tags: ionic-framework

I started working with ionic recently and ran into an issue where my data was not being updated on re-entering the views. On finding more about ionic, I realized we can disable the caching for that view and Ionic is forced to recreate the view each time.

However, when I use `$state.go('stateName',{},{reload: true})` and ionic caching disabled, I get another issue.

> My controller is called twice for that view and the navbar
>   disappears.

The same issue is open at ionic [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3852). Also there has been some discussion about the issue [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hidden-nav-bar-using-state-go-with-disabled-caching-beta-14/17686) on ionic forum. However, the proposed solution of marking `hide-nav-bar="false"` does not work for me.

With the solution of

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
    });
```

My navbar becomes visible but with NO buttons, and also, the controller is being called twice.

Since this should be a very very common scenario for any app which does not need view caching, could anyone please share any appropriate workaround figured out to get past this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `{reload: true}` in your `$state.go` method to update the data in your view because this is what is causing the controller to be called twice.

Since ionic caches the controller, in order to update data every time you redirect to the view you can use the `$ionicView` lifecycle hooks namely `beforeEnter`, `enter`, `loaded` etc.

```
.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
     // Fetch your data here so that it will be updated every time you redirect to this view
   })
});
```

This is a very scalable approach for fetching data in controllers

More details about the lifecycle methods can be found here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionView/